# How to get the ID of a record from an other table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a database in MySQL and I want to migrate it, changing the structure of the tables a little bit.

I am new to MySQL, so bear with me, please.

I have the following tables:

**Addresses**

- address_id
- address (example: 55th Street)
- zip_code
- city
- country

**CustomersOld**

- customer_id
- name
- billing_address
- billing_zip_code
- billing_city
- billing_country

I want to migrate the customers data into a new table with the following structure

**CustomersNew**

- customer_id
- billing_address_id (foreign key for the Addresses table)

So, I want to take the 4 billing address fields from the table *CustomersOld* and do this:

1. Check whether the Addresses table contains a record matching the billing address fields.

   1.1. If yes, then only return the AddressID.

   1.2. If no, then create that record, and return the AddressID.
2. Insert the AddressID in the CustomersNew table, in the address_id field.

Normally, I use this simple script to migrate a table:

```
INSERT INTO CustomersNew
SELECT * FROM CustomersOld
```

I suppose I would have to perform some nested SELECTs and JOINs:

```
INSERT INTO CustomersNew
    (customer_id, billing_address_id)
SELECT
    customer_id, 
    -- SELECT/JOIN ... (something like that, in order to get the address_id)
FROM CustomersOld
```

Could you help me in getting the appropriate `billing_address_id`, for each customer, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done in two steps. First create all the `Addresses` records:

```
INSERT INTO Addresses (address, zip_code, city, country)
SELECT DISTINCT billing_address, billing_zip_code, billing_city, billing_country
FROM CustomersOld;
```

Then create all the `CustomersNew` records by joining this table with `CustomersOld`

```
INSERT INTO CustomersNew (customer_id, billing_address_id)
SELECT c.customer_id, a.address_id
FROM CustomersOld AS c
JOIN Addresses AS a ON c.billing_address = a.address AND c.billing_zip_code = a.zip_code AND c.billing_city = a.city AND c.billing_country = a.country
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this way

Firts align the adderesses to the last CustomerOld address

```
insert into Addresses (address, zip_code, city, country )
select billing_address, billing_zip_code, billing_city, billing_country
from CustomerOld
where (billing_address, billing_zip_code, billing_city, billing_country ) not in 
            ( select address, zip_code, city, country
              from Addresses
              )
```

then create and populate CustomersNew with a create select

```
create table CustomersNew
select a.customer_id, b.address_id
from CustomersOld as a 
inner join Addresses as b  on a.billing_address = b.address
    and a.billing_zip_code = b.zip_code
      and  a.billing_city = b.city
        and a. billing_country = b.country
```